# Backup EC2 instance to external hard drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to backup a Windows EC2 instance onto an external hard drive or S3 bucket. So far i have not been able to find anything that will help me do the same. I only know of the snapshot and AMI creation for the backup which i don't seem to be able to download either. Is it even possible to back them up externally? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Windows or Linux? And what is your use for this backup?

Comment: It is Windows. I need to provide the instance copy/snapshot/image/backup as part of one of the project requirements. The copy will be provided to third party (not part of our cloud structure) who should be able to recreate the same instance from the backup if necessary.

Comment: Cloudberry lists several methods.  If you backup to an S3 bucket you could give them access to that one backup long enough for them to copy it to their own storage, or download it yourself to the external HD - https://www.cloudberrylab.com/resources/blog/backup-aws-ec2-instance/

Comment: Have you tried to export it as a VM? i.e. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html

Comment: @DaveS the snapshot gets saved to some S3 bucket as far as i am aware. But Amazon hides that S3 bucket though. not sure how to unhide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem isn't the backup... it's **how you intend to restore the backup** so that it can be used.

For example, think about how you would 'backup' a normal PC such that it can be restored in case of failure. This typically needs some form of **backup software** to make a bootable disk.

You can run normal backup software on an Amazon EC2 Windows instance (in fact, Windows includes such a capability itself), then **download the backup file**. Then, use the normal method to **restore it** (which would depend upon the way you made the backup).

I would recommend **doing a test restore**, to confirm that the process actually works correctly.

Comment: Another method would be to create a `.iso` file of the disk, then download the file. However, not sure if the restored image would boot on a normal PC.